# How to fetch multiple dimensions from google analytics in one API call

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I trying to fetch multiple dimension values for single metrics .i am getting an error as

"{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Unknown dimension(s): ga:sourceMedium,ga:deviceCategory", "errors": [ { "message": "Unknown dimension(s): ga:sourceMedium,ga:deviceCategory", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }".

it is workign fine if i m sending single dimension value 
"$browser->setName("ga:sourceMedium"); "

```
$VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXXX";

// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate($pulldate);//YYYY-mm-dd
$dateRange->setEndDate($pulldate);////YYYY-mm-dd

// Create the Metrics object.
 $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("sessions");

$browser = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();      
$browser->setName("ga:sourceMedium,ga:deviceCategory");  


// Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setDimensions(array($browser));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a new instance for `Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension()` for each dimension like:

```
$sourceMedium = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$sourceMedium->setName("ga:sourceMedium");

$deviceCategory = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$deviceCategory->setName("ga:deviceCategory");
```

Then when you `setDimensions()` you should do it like this:

```
$request->setDimensions(array($sourceMedium, $deviceCategory));
```

Easy?

Comment: Still a valid answer in January 2018. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample 
This is the way to add multiple Dimensions and metrics..

ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest().setViewId(VIEW_ID).setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange)).setDimensions(Arrays.asList(browser,browserVersion)).setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions));

Comment: Did you read the question properly? Code is in PHP and not JAVA.